# Cloudera Sentry with LDAP - Unable to add user as Sentry admin

Tags: apache, postgresql, hadoop, apache-sentry

Background:

By default the Sentry service has the users `hive`, `hue` and `impala` as the sentry admins. This is w.r.t to the property on Cloudera Manager (CM) `sentry.service.admin.group`. I want to add a user or group which has my user account, so that I can become the Sentry admin.

Current environment:

1. Cloudera 5.4.7 with CM
2. Postgres databases for CDH, Hive and Sentry
3. Sentry version 1.4

Question:

I have integrated OpenLDAP so that Beeline authentication can be done through LDAP user and password credentials. Before LDAP integration to HiveServer2, I used root as the Sentry admin, (Beeline does not strictly check for password without LDAP) so I could execute commands like `show roles;` and `create roles;` as `root`.

Now with LDAP integrated I cannot login as `root`, since it does not have an entry on the LDAP server and adding it there is not an option, so I want to add a user called `johndoe` as the admin for Sentry so that he can create roles like how `root` did.

Is this something that I need to set at a Postgres level? I mean by entering the Sentry database and `GRANT`'ing some privilege there?

What have I tried so far:

1. I have tried all combinations of using local users in the property `sentry.service.admin.group`, adding local users to the `hive` group, using LDAP users, LDAP groups - Nothing !
2. I don't understand where it is going wrong. Or is it that Sentry only identifies `hive`, `hue` and `impala` as the admins.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Stuck on this for ten days now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the Unix group to which the Unix-User you are using belongs. Sentry can only use the Unix group, which in the case of Hive, Hue and Impala in the default configuration is hive, hue and impala.

**Sentry cannot use LDAP groups. You need to use Unix groups in the setting sentry.service.admin.group.**

Comment: It might be possible to workaround this restriction by using [an extension for Sentry which authenticates users from an LDAP server and auto-adds them to the an organization in Sentry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentry-ldap-auth).